# Asp.Net-core Docker container not running on raspberry pi

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, raspberry-pi2

So I'm not sure what information is required here, but I'm going to try my best, I've built a small website that runs in dotnet-core, more specifically dotnet-core 2.0:`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>`.

I have installed docker on my raspberry pi:

> pi@swarm-1:~ $ docker --version
>   Docker version 18.01.0-ce, build 03596f5

I have also managed to install dot net core 2.0 on there as well through this guide

> https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2017/07/23/running-a-net-core-2-app-on-raspbian-jessie-and-deploying-to-the-pi-with-cake/

---

> pi@swarm-1:~ $ dotnet --info
>     Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
>     Version  : 2.0.4
>     Build    : 7f262f453d8c8479b9af91d34c013b3aa05bc1ff`

I have downloaded a docker image onto my pi:

> pi@swarm-1:~ $ docker images
>   REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
>   joro550/radiusnet   latest              d579944265b0        16 hours ago        349MB

When I run the docker run command I do get a id back from docker:

> pi@swarm-1:~ $ docker run -d -p 8080:80 joro550/radiusnet
>   d5c579332abef8cf1938ef7a88aea43e3e84380099e44e2adee7fca196a49de9

but when I list my running containers with ps I get an emty list:

> pi@swarm-1:~ $ docker ps
>   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
>   pi@swarm-1:~ $

I have tried to run docker ps -a:

[image: putty screenshot of docker ps -a]

The contents of the dockerfile if this is useful for anyone:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY /src ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/src/RadiusNet.Web/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RadiusNet.Web.dll"]`
```

Intestingly when I run dotnet *.dll

I get the error message:

> pi@swarm-1:~ $ dotnet helloworld.dll
>   Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
>     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

Following the Debian guide for the dotnet-core install give me this:
[image: error message for dotnet-core]

If there is anything I missed please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research and a lot of trial and error I believe it was an issue with my docker file, updated docker file below:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY /src ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out -r linux-arm

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.0-runtime-stretch-arm32v7
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/src/RadiusNet.Web/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RadiusNet.Web.dll"]
```